# How to add native icons in Qt action?

Tags: qt, qt4, icons, qaction

this is my Qt code

```
openAction = new QAction("Open", this);
openAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Open);
```

I know I could add a Icon for this `Action` by this

```
openAction->setIcon(QIcon("file path from source file"));
```

But I hope I could add `Native` icon like this

[image]

How should I do?

---

Yes! Yes! Yes! I got my answer by myself

You can use this:

```
QIcon QIcon::fromTheme ( const QString & name, 
                         const QIcon & fallback = QIcon() ) [static]
```

Comment: Please post an answer to your question instead of putting it in the question itself. It makes it easier for other users to see that the question has been answered.